# Is a cross trainer helpful for jogging?

Tags: jogging, crossfit, joints

**Question:** Is a cross trainer a good muscle preparation for jogging? Or is there a better, also joint friendly alternative to train the body for jogging?

**Background**
Jogging is pretty intense for joints, especially the knees. I want to avoid damage on the knees, thus, I want to train my muscles before starting to jog. I wonder whether the movements on a cross trainer are helpful in this case. In my understanding a cross trainer is like a light, joint friendly version of jogging which could prepare my muscles for the real runs.

Comment: Firstly, why did you get the MRT/MRI if you had no pain? Secondly, if your doctor told you you can jog, why not just put some shoes on and go jog? It sounds like you're massively and unnecessarily overcomplicating this.

Comment: @DavidScarlett I edited the question. The answers are: (Firstly) I had a pain and that was why the MRT was done. Then, after some time the pain was gone. (Secondly, ) After jogging some times the pain came back. But the doctor said I shall not jog if the pain returns. That is the problem. Since I am completely untrained I want to build the necessary muscles before going for the actual run.

Comment: How new/old are your shoes? Are they specific to running? N=1, when I was running x-country I would get 3-500 miles out of a pair of shoes, so I was going through a pair about once a month. Anything more than that and I started getting various pains.

Comment: We don't handle medical questions here, and this is a question that you shouldn't even ask to just any doctor or physio, you should ask *your* doctor or physio.

Comment: @IgorstandswithUkraine I recommend revising the question then to focus on the transference of cross training to road jogging, without the injury related context.

Comment: @IgorstandswithUkraine Looks good, voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I talked to two sport coaches I met and they said it is a terrible idea to use a cross trainer to prepare for running. The cross trainer does train your general fitness, but it doesn't help you with your running techniques nor with the muscles that are responsible for soften the impact of the steps. Thus, after training with the cross trainer you do the worst - you can run a long while but you do it in the worst way for your joints.

Instead using the cross trainer they recommended me to simply walk as much as possible. The mechanics in walking are closer to running then it is the case for the cross trainer, hence walking is a joints friendly way to train the muscles for jogging. After a while (weeks or months, depending how often and how much one walks) one can gradually increase the speed and make it step by step more running then walking.

Comment: Why this or that when you can both and?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Not sure whether I get your question right. Why not doing walking and cross trainer? You can do so but as explained in the answer the cross trainer sessions will not help you making jogging better for your joints and that is what the question was about..